# Changing HDMI diplay for specific scrrens programmatically (PI-4)

Tags: java, linux, kotlin, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-os

I have a Raspberry PI 4 with a dual display setup I wanted to show different operations on both displays depending on some logic.

My application is built with compose multiplatform I can make two screens by just following the code

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = application {

    Window(
        onCloseRequest = app::onDestroy, title = " WINDOW 1 ", state = 
    rememberWindowState(
            placement = WindowPlacement.Fullscreen
        )
    ) {
        App(app)
    }

    Window(
        onCloseRequest = app::onDestroy, title = " WINDOW 2 ", state = 
     rememberWindowState(
            placement = WindowPlacement.Fullscreen
        )
    ) {
        App(app)
    }
   
}
```

But I want to set WINDOW 1 to HDMI 1 and WINDOW 2 to HDMI 2 in full screen programmatically any idea how can I do that?

Can anyone help me with it I tried using screen but no luck

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```